# print first and last n rows in a loop | awk

Tags: shell, awk

I have a text file with n numbers of rows, i want to print first line followed by the last n lines and so on

I have written a code as below but wanted it to run in a loop till the time all rows are covered.

```
cat test6.txt | awk '{a[NR]=$0} NR<=1 {print} END{for (i=NR-n;i<=NR;i++) print a[i]}' n=3
```

cat test6.txt

```
abc1
abc2
abc3
abc4
abc5
abc6
abc7
abc8
abc9
abc10
abc11
abc12
abc13
```

So it's output should be

```
abc1
abc11
abc12
abc13
abc2
abc8
abc9
abc10
abc3
abc5
abc6
abc7
abc4
```

Comment: First of all, since you seem to seek an `awk` solution, I suggest that you tag your question as _awk_, not _shell_, because it doesn't seem related to POSIX shell. Second, I think that your code is more maintainable, if you do the whole logic inside the `END` block. While you can do it completely in awk, I would find the problem easier to structure in a more general language (Java, Ruby, Perl, .... - whatever you are familiar with).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
{ a[NR] = $0 }
END {
    end = NR
    for (i=1; i in a; i++) {
        print a[i]
        delete a[i]
        for (j=end-n+1; j<=end; j++) {
            if ( j in a ) {
                print a[j]
                delete a[j]
            }
        }
        end -= n
    }
}
```

.

```
$ awk -v n=3 -f tst.awk file
abc1
abc11
abc12
abc13
abc2
abc8
abc9
abc10
abc3
abc5
abc6
abc7
abc4
```

Answer (score 0):

another `awk`

```
$ awk -v c=3 '{a[NR]=$0} 
          END {k=NR; 
               for(i=1;i<=k;i++) 
                 {print a[i]; 
                  for(n=c; i<k && n--; k--) print a[k]}}' file
```